# How do I style an external SVG file, included in my HTML, with no symbol name?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG file that looks like this (the value for the `d` attribute omitted for brevity):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512"><path d="..."/></svg>
```

I would like to embed this file in HTML (without including the SVG source inline). I know that there are multiple ways to do this, you can use `<img src="file.svg">`, `<object data="file.svg">` and so forth. I want to be able to style this SVG file using CSS (in my case, to make colours match the colour of text in the HTML). I also don't want to use symbol names, since none of the SVG files at my disposal use symbols.

So far, I haven't found a solution that meets all three of these requirements. To re-iterate:

1. The HTML code needs to reference an external SVG file
2. It must be possible to style the SVG image using external CSS
3. It must not require that the SVG file have within it a symbol name.

If it's not possible, let me know, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: I think it should be possible cause when I try to do this with google dev tools I can select a path and give it `fill: black;` to make a path black. (I implemented the svg using `<embed src="path_to_upload" type="image/svg+xml"> ), I don't know how to style this with a css file tho

Comment: Would it be a solution to pack all SVG files together into one sprite sheet once, giving them Ids on the way? There are libraries like [svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite) or [webpack modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin) that can help with that.

Comment: It's not possible to style it without the svg somehow ending up inline. For a pre-packaged solution to inject external svg into your html, take a look at [svg-inject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible if the SVG does not have a fill color defined in its code. I could be mistaken. Have you tried something like this?

**HTML**

```
<svg class="icon-1">
   <use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

**SOURCE:**
https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/

Comment: Isn't `#icon-1` a symbol name? In my example, nothing in my SVG file is named `icon-1`. I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to modify the original SVG file.